# jQuery AJAX and ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this little problem...
I have this asp.net website.
I have a menu, all done with html and css.
So when I click on home, the ajax loads the other content into the specified div element.
Working 100%.

In the content that was loaded into the div element, I have a button. An ASP.NET button.

When I click on the button, it gives me a "The resource cannot be found." error.

There must be something I am missing. If you dont understand, heres the ajax:

```
//Load the Home page on click.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.home').click(function () {
        $("#content").load("html/home/home.aspx");
    });
});
```

Now the aspx page that was loaded into the content div, displays a button, btnAdd:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAddNewBlog" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddNewBlog" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" />
</asp:Panel>
```

When I click on that button, the error appears.

What I want to achieve is to: when the user clicks on the button, the text in txtAddNewBlog gets added into a database. Now this I can achieve using C#... but not if this error is in my way. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `html/home/home.aspx` exist? Try looking at the network request the browser is sending. Navigate to that URL to ensure it exists.

Comment: yes, it exists, because the ajax loads all the content in home.aspx into #content and I can see it. but when I click on the botton. This works when I dont have ajax loading the content... but when ajax comes in it does not work any more

Comment: Is the `#content` placed inside some other form ? If yes then you break the html struct when you load the other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is going to be the `form` that gets created. When you make that request, ASP.NET will build a form whose target is `home.aspx`, not the full path to it. But you're dumping that form onto an HTML page that's at a different level.

When you do a form post, it attempts to post to `home.aspx`, relative to where the browser thinks it is, which is two levels up, and it doesn't find it.

I don't know if there's a good way to do this - ASP.NET is not meant to handle this kind of thing. You can do an IFRAME. You can wrap the `home.aspx` content into a user control, and leave the ASP.NET form on the outer page. Or you may be able to manipulate the form's target so you post to the right place. But I don't think any of those would be a lot of fun.

Comment: so is is better to create webforms and just "Response.Redirect" them and reload the whole page???

Comment: My opinion, yes, with the current architecture, best bet would be to actually redirect rather than AJAX-ify it. The user has to deal with page reloads, but most of the web still works that way. If you want to avoid that, I'd recommend building a solution without the ASP.NET WebForms page lifecycle - single-page apps are generally very javascript-intensive, so the architecture would be very different from a traditional WebForms app. Your server code could handle building traditional markup and posts, leaving navigation for client code.